# C#: Passing a value between classes (Error CS0120)

Tags: c#, class

In the code below I get an error when I try to call the array from an other class. What went wrong?

Error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `learningcsharp.Wall.Ar' (CS0120)

```
using System;

namespace learningcsharp
{
    public class Wall
    {
        private int[] _ar;
        public int[] Ar
        {
            get
            {
                return _ar;
            }
            set
            {
                _ar = value;
            }   
        }

        public void build()
        {
            Ar = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
        }
    }

    public class Draw
    {
        public void draw()
        {
            Console.WriteLine (Wall.Ar[1]);   // ERROR CS0120
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Wall wall = new Wall ();
            wall.build ();
            Draw draw = new Draw ();
            draw.draw ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See the answer below. You are treating Wall like a static class, when you need to create an instance of the class before you can use it. Do some reading on static classes and it may clear up your confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of Wall to draw method as parameter

```
public class Draw
{
    public void draw(Wall wall)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (wall.Ar[1]);
    }
}
```

And you can call it like:

```
 public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Wall wall = new Wall ();
        wall.build ();
        Draw draw = new Draw ();
        draw.draw (wall);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error litterally explained what to do, but here is a example from Jamie Dixon's post: [Object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343504/object-reference-for-non-static-field-in-c-sharp)

This is from the Offical MSDM page: [Creating objects/classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx)
I think that is exactly what you need.

I hope this helps you out.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Or simply mark array as static:

```
private static int[] _ar;
```

also with property.